# Is there a way to pass multiple CMD to Dockerfile as ARG?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to pass 2 commands to Dockerfile to be executed one after another, but have had no luck since:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
ARG COMMAND
ENV COMMAND=${COMMAND}
CMD "${COMMAND}"
```

docker.compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  check_requirements:
    image: my_test_image
    build:
      args:
        COMMAND: "echo 1; echo 2"
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

when I run `docker compose build` and then `docker compose run test` (or `docker container run -it my_test_image`) I get:

```
/bin/sh: echo 1; echo 2: not found
```

If I substitute last line of Dockerfile with:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "${COMMAND}"]
```

I get

```
1; echo 2
```

Expected:
on CMD Docker runs `echo 1` and then `echo 2`

Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to pass <strike>2 commands</strike> a script to Dockerfile to be executed

Sure, then write the script content to a file and execute.

```
ARG COMMAND
ENV COMMAND=${COMMAND}
RUN printenv COMMAND > /script.sh
CMD ["sh", "/script.sh"]
```

Or you can call eval to evaluate the content of an environment variable.

```
ARG COMMAND
ENV COMMAND=${COMMAND}
CMD ["sh", "-c", "eval \"$COMMAND\""]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just override the command when you run the container.  You do not need to try to marshal it through an environment variable or build `ARG`.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  check_requirements:
    build: .
    command: sh -c 'echo 1; echo 2'
```

I'd suggest making the Dockerfile `CMD` be the "default" thing you expect a container to do.  This is one of a couple of things I would not make parameterized; just declare a fixed `CMD` and allow it to be overridden when you run the container.  (One specific example that comes to mind is a Python application where the default `CMD` runs a Django application but you can override Compose `command:` to run a Celery worker from the same code base.)